# How come Django models not enforcing required model field when not specified?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I created a model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    content = models.TextField()
```

and the corresponding test:
from django.test import TestCase

```
from .models import Example


class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Example.objects.create(name="fff", content="blah blah blah")

    def test_length_of_toa_model(self):
        """example model should have length 1 as we created one in setUp"""
        length_of_toa = len(Example.objects.all())
        self.assertEqual(length_of_toa, 1)
```

I remember the default behaviour was it will throw error as code is by default required field and not set to null or blank, so why in this case everything works fine?
Also apart from the test, I tried created and saving using django shell and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

when you create object by manager ( the .objects ) you directly construct sql query, so you dont have any field verification. when you create/save objects by django form, before create the form check all fields by running full_clean methods,

for enforcing clean verification , you cand add full_clean in save like :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ....

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.full_clean() # if error(field cant blank ..ect) raise a ValidationError 
       super().save(*args, kwargs
```

you can also add constraints directly in databse by constrains methods like :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   username = models.TextField()
 
   class Meta:
        constraints = [
             models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(username__isnull=true), name='username_cant_be_empty')  # the username can be empty
        ]
        # when you save this with username empty, integrityError error raised,
```

check more here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/constraints/

Comment: I am not sure if this answers my question. I remember it used to throw error when trying to save a model with a field not filled in. Here code field is not set to null nor blank.